# Better Database design for hibernatre?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, database-design, database-normalization

I am new to database design. I am using MySQL

I have a **Form** table which contains a field **Country**

Since the values in this columns can be one from the country list only, so I made this column **int** instead of **varchar** and put the list in a new table. shown as below:

1. Instead of having country column like

`country varchar(255) NOT NULL`

2. I made it countryCode with datatype INT and added a Foreign Key to table **CountryMaster** which is shown as below

`...
countryCode INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (countryCode) REFERENCES CountryMaster (countryCode),
...`

`create table CountryMaster(
    countryCode INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);`

It is working fine, but the issue is that the same table contains many more column like **formStatus** (with possible values Draft, Saved, Approved), **gender** (Male, Female), **bloodGroup** (A, B, O), **rHFactor** (+ve, -ve), **occupation** (Service, Business, Student, Unemployed) etc. If I will make separate table for each such column I will end up in 20 to 25 Master tables.

I also tried to put all such Master Date in a single table i.e. **CommonMaster** with columns **type, key and value** shown as below:

`create table CommonMaster(
    commonCode INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    key  INT NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);`

with values like:

```
   code type       key value
     7  BLOOD_GROUP 1   A
     8  BLOOD_GROUP 2   B
     9  BLOOD_GROUP 3   O
    10  RH_FACTOR   1   +ve
    11  RH_FACTOR   2   -ve
    12  OCCUPATION  1   Service
    13  OCCUPATION  2   Profession
    14  OCCUPATION  3   Business
    15  OCCUPATION  4   Student
    16  OCCUPATION  5   Unemployeed
```

I want to know that what is a better approach and why. I also have to use hibernate orm in the project. So the design should be pertaining to that.

Comment: Either approach is fine.  You can have hundreds of master tables (I call them domain tables), or you can have one common master table.  I'd watch to see if your database winds up waiting for the common master table.to service SELECT requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer a hundreds master tables than a common table with all the types; more structure, more organization, more adaptive for add, delete and update the value of then, also for reports.